# How do you view computed items when creating UCM transcripts?

Tags: unison-lang

Given the following transcript:

````
```ucm:hide
.> pull https://github.com/unisonweb/base:v3:.releases._latest .base
```

```unison
foo = List.map (x -> x * 2) [1,2,3]
```


```ucm
.> add foo
.> view foo
```
````

When this is executed, I get the following output:

````
```unison
foo = List.map (x -> x * 2) [1,2,3]
```

```ucm

  I found and typechecked these definitions in scratch.u. If you
  do an `add` or `update`, here's how your codebase would
  change:
  
    ⍟ These new definitions are ok to `add`:
    
      foo : [Nat]

```
```ucm
.> add foo

  ⍟ I've added these definitions:
  
    foo : [Nat]

.> view foo

  foo : [Nat]
  foo =
    use Nat *
    List.map (x -> x * 2) [1, 2, 3]

```
````

I understand why it is this way but is there an alternative approach that would show the computed value of `foo` (i.e. `[2, 4, 6`]), as if we're working in a `scratch.u` file?

I also tried:

````
```ucm
.> foo

```
````

But get the error `I don't know how to foo.`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, try `display foo`. :)

The naming is a bit weird. We keep thinking of renaming `view` to `source`, and then maybe leave `display` (or rename it to `eval` and allow arbitrary expressions, like a REPL).